# How to position Syncfusion datepicker calendar to open on top?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am using Syncfusion datepicker in my angular project. I have a bootstrap modal which opens up on button click. When clicking on the calendar icon which opens the calendar is not clearly visible. Any CSS i can implement to make it open on top or make it scrollable. Zindex of modal is 1050 and zindex of calendar is always +1 which is 1051.

[image: demo picture of above scenrio]